# Displaying a PartialView with updated data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

C#, MVC4

I have a PartialView created for a popup data entry on a form.  This is a snippet from the main form.

```
    <input type="button" id="btnAddGroup" value="Add Group" />

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</div>
</fieldset> }
```

I discovered quickly that I needed to have the line:

```
@Html.Partial("_Groups")
```

Outside the primary view so the form submit button in the partial view would accept and process.

My controller processes and sends back the data using:

```
            return PartialView(NewModel);
```

I can run the debugger and see that the data is getting passed back to the PartialView but since the view sits outside the original form, it's not displaying.

My PartialView is as follows:

```
    @model OMD.ViewModels.SearchedUser

@if (Model.AddGroups != null)
{
    <h2>Groups to be Added</h2>

    <table id="AddGroupList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Until
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Group in Model.AddGroups)
            { 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.GroupName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.dtAddedTo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.bAddOrRemove)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (AuthCheck.CheckUser(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), oRoles.StaffChangeRequest) || 
                        AuthCheck.CheckUser(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), oRoles.StudentChangeRequest))
                        { 
                            <span>@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveGroup", new { id = Group.ID })</span>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

<div id="dlgAddGroup" title="Add Group" style="display: none">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Groups",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId ="ID",OnSuccess="onSuccess"}))
```

{

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AllGroups,new SelectList(Model.AllGroups, "ID","GroupName"), "Select Group to Add")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AllGroups)

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBox("cbxMakeGroupPermanent", true)  Permanent
</div>
<div class="editor-label" id ="dlgUntil1">
    Group Add Until:  
</div>
<div class="editor-field" id="dlgUntil2">
    @Html.TextBox("tbAddUntil",null,new { maxlength = 30, style = "width: 100px" })
    <span style='padding:5px'><img id='calImageGroup' alt="img" src='~/Images/calendar.gif'></span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit">add</button>
```

}

I can see the table at the top display the information posted back to it but it doesn't show on the screen...

How can I get this data/table to display?

Comment: Why aren't you doing it with Ajax ? On success you could fill a `<div>` element with rendered html received from server

Comment: I'm good with C# but not so with Ajax.  Do you have an example?